# changing multiple images by textbox (javascript)

Tags: javascript, image, textbox

I am quite new to javascripting and maybe the answer is quite easy, but I don't get it. I want to change images by an input in a textbox. So a part by a picture-path should be replaced by the value typed into the textbox. It works fine for ONE picture and ONE textbox, but I want at least 10 textboxes and the individual value should be assigned to one of the 10 pictures. Moreover, upto now I have to reload the page to change the picture a second time. This shouldn't be case. Can someone give me a hint or solution? I googled quite a lot, but I am not aware for what I should search. The tiny source is below...

thanks

The javascript part:

```
window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementById( 'inpPG' ).onchange = keyUpPG;
}

function keyUpPG()
{
var img = document.getElementById( 'pg' );
img.src = img.src.replace( /chris_paul.png/ , this.value + '.png');
}

window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementById( 'inpSG' ).onchange = keyUpSG;
}

function keyUpSG()
{
var img = document.getElementById( 'sg' );
img.src = img.src.replace( /eric_gordon.png/ , this.value + '.png');
}
```

and so on...

and the body-part:

```
<center>
PF <input type="text" id="inpPF"> C <input type="text" id="inpC"> SF <input type="text" id="inpSF"><br>

<img id="pf" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/kevin_love.png">
<img id="c" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/joakim_noah.png">
<img id="sf" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/harrison_barnes.png">

<br>PG <input type="text" id="inpPG"> SG <input type="text" id="inpSG"><br>
<img id="pg" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/chris_paul.png">
<img id="sg" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/eric_gordon.png">

<br><input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like this simple,using jquery

```
 $('#inpPG').on('change', function() {
          $('#pg').attr('src','http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/'+this.value);
        });

    $('#inpSG').on('change', function() {
              $('#sg').attr('src','http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/statscube/players/large/'+this.value);
            });
```

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SvJxX/1/)**

**test by entering this -->kevin_love.png in PG or SG TEXTBOX**